# What does "{Binding Path=.}" mean in WPF binding?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, xaml

What does `{Binding Path=.}` mean in a WPF binding?

I see some people use it, but couldn't find any explanation.

Are there any other special symbols in binding syntax (other than `{Binding /}`)?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

This is shorthand for binding to the current source.  For more info see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path.aspx).

From the documentation specifically:

> Optionally, a period (.) path can be used to bind to the current
>   source. For example, `Text="{Binding}"` is equivalent to `Text="{Binding Path=.}"`.

Comment: @Ray - my thoughts exactly.  If you're going to shorthand, why stop there?

Comment: I can't argue with MSDN, but there still a difference. {Binding} cannot be used on an object itself (being two way it requires a property) while {Binding Path=.} works.

Comment: @Sergey - Do you have a code sample where {Binding} doesn't work but {Binding Path=.} does?  If so, MSDN probably needs to get updated...

Comment: Easily: 
var s = "test;
DataContext=s;

and in <TextBox Text={Binding}/> - does not work. But MSDN is not wiki...

Comment: Another exemple : <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter=...}"/> does not work because you have to set the Path. In that case Path=. is useful.

Comment: {Binding} and {Binding Path=.} are not exactly equal. This [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488014/are-binding-path-and-binding-really-equal) points out the difference.

Comment: So `Visibility="{Binding IsReadOnly}` is the same as `Visibility="{Binding path=IsReadOnly}` ?

Answer (score 89):

I found this [WPF Binding CheatSheet](http://www.nbdtech.com/blog/archive/2009/02/22/wpf-data-binding-cheat-sheet-update-the-internationalization-fix.aspx) a few months back and find it very useful, especially for anyone learning WPF. There are some spelling mistakes within it, but it is still quite good.

Here is a small excerpt (which is supposed to have tabular formatting):

| Basic Binding |  |
| --- | --- |
| {Binding} | Bind to current DataContext. |
| {Binding Name} | Bind to the “Name” property of the current DataContext. |
| {Binding Name.Length} | Bind to the Length property of the object in the Name property of the current DataContext. |
| {Binding ElementName=SomeTextBox, Path=Text} | Bind to the “Text” property of the element XAML element with name=”SomeTextBox” or x:Name=”SomeTextBox”. |

[Direct link to CheatSheet](http://www.nbdtech.com/Free/WpfBinding.pdf)

Comment: nice one but what is {Binding .}. I am searching explanation for this one but I cant find it?

Comment: @batmaci I want to say it's equivalent to `{Binding }`, but it's been quite a few years since I've worked much with Xaml, so I'm not sure.

Comment: @batmaci, years later... `{Binding string}` is similar to `{Binding Path=string}`. `string` is not used to initialize the property `Path` directly, but as a parameter for the constructor `Binding (string path)` which then initializes `Path` property. This works only when the string is the first token after `Binding`, the rest being regular initializers (property=value pairs). Knowing that, `Binding .` is in effect equal to `Binding Path=.` and property Path syntax is available [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/propertypath-xaml-syntax?view=netframework-4.8).