# DataTemplate in ControlTemplate not updating Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I've created a control with 3 PART_s, one PART_ changes depending on the type bound to it, however values changed within the Control do not update the Binding, it seems to work as OneWay Binding.

Here's part of the code I beleive is relevant:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="BooleanDAView" DataType="{x:Type sys:Boolean}">
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding ., Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="DateTimeDAView" DataType="{x:Type sys:DateTime}">
    <extToolkit:DateTimePicker Value="{Binding ., Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="Int32DAView"  DataType="{x:Type sys:Int32}">
    <extToolkit:IntegerUpDown Value="{Binding ., Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="StringDAView"  DataType="{x:Type sys:String}">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ., Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

....

```
<ContentControl x:Name="PART_Content"
        Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
        Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
        Content="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}"
        >
    <ContentControl.ContentTemplateSelector>
        <controls:TypeBasedDataTemplateSelector>
            <controls:TypeBasedDataTemplateSelector.Templates>
                <controls:TypedDictionary>
                    <sys:String x:Key="{x:Type sys:Boolean}">BooleanDAView</sys:String>
                    <sys:String x:Key="{x:Type sys:DateTime}">DateTimeDAView</sys:String>
                    <sys:String x:Key="{x:Type sys:Int32}">Int32DAView</sys:String>
                    <sys:String x:Key="{x:Type sys:String}">StringDAView</sys:String>
                </controls:TypedDictionary>
            </controls:TypeBasedDataTemplateSelector.Templates>
        </controls:TypeBasedDataTemplateSelector>
    </ContentControl.ContentTemplateSelector>
</ContentControl>
```

For Content I've also tried ... `RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:DABaseControl}` but no change.

If the DataTemplate Binding use `"{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}"` the template doesn't change once set.

Or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

I just encountered the same problem, I wanted to create a `DataTemplate` with `DataType="{x:Type sys:Boolean}` that just had a checkbox. But there were many warning signs along the way telling me this isn't the way it should be done.

At first, the simple binding of `{Binding}` would throw an exception "*Two-way binding requires path or xpath*", which was the first warning sign. I changed the binding to `{Binding .}` which worked (even though [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path.aspx) clearly states that they're equivalent). That fact that voodoo was helping was the second warning sign. It then displayed correctly and the checked state was according to the boolean value, but when clicking the checkbox (even with `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`), it refused to update the binding source, no matter what I tried. Using `diagnostics:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High` showed that it didn't even try to bind back (third warning sign).

I went ahead and created a simple "box" for the bool value - a class with a single bool property named `Value` with an`INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation. I changed the binding to `{Binding Value}` and now everything worked, including two way binding.

**Conclusion:** It seems a binding can't update the bound object itself, but only properties of that object (which is why `{Binding}` throws an exception, but the more explicit `{Binding .}` suppresses that exception, according to [H.B.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11804671/149265)). In any case, the approach of creating a ViewModel and creating templates that target it appears to be more than a mere design guideline, but an actual technical requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually never worked with a `ContentTemplateSelector`, but if I had to hazard a guess I would say either it's not responding to `PropertyChanged` events on your `ContentControl.Content` property, or your `Content` binding is incorrect.

You can easily check if your binding is correct or not by removing the `ContentTemplateSelector` and seeing if data shows up at all. If it does, your binding is correct. If it doesn't, it's incorrect and you need to fix it.

If the problem is the `ContentTemplateSelector`, then I would suggest switching to a `DataTrigger` which determines which `ContentTemplate` to use based on the Content. This is what I usually do, and it uses a Converter which simply returns `typeof(value)`

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
     <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource StringDAView}" />
     <Style.Triggers>
         <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ObjectToTypeConverter}" 
                      Value="{x:Type sys:Boolean">
             <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource BooleanDAView}" />
         </DataTrigger>
         <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ObjectToTypeConverter}" 
                      Value="{x:Type DateTime">
             <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource DateTimeDAView}" />
         </DataTrigger>
         <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ObjectToTypeConverter}" 
                      Value="{x:Type sys:Int32">
             <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource Int32DAView}" />
         </DataTrigger>
     </Style.Triggers>
 </Style>
```

Comment: The `ContentTemplateSelector` does display the correct value and representation, and the value displayed will update if it's bound property is changed (Behaving like `OneWay`), but if the value is changed using say the `TextBox` displayed within the control it will **not** update the bound property.
  I also tried the DataTrigger method but with similar results.

Comment: @user1049761 My guess would be it has something to do with you binding the `Content` property to the Template's `Content` value. I don't know for sure what's wrong because I can't see the `Template` that contains the `ContentControl`, however try binding to `{TemplateBinding DataContext}` instead of `{TemplateBinding Content}`

Comment: Thanks prodded me in the right direction, now I need to figure out what exactly solved the problem.