# WPF TextBlock text Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, user-controls

the TextBlock binding does not work and I cant figure why...

(This Code Works but the TextBlock does not get Updated )

**XAML**

```xml
<TextBlock x:Name="filterAllText"
 Text="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

**Codebehind**

```
filterAllText.DataContext = LogSession.test.MyCoynt;
```

**C#**

```
public class Test : INotifyPropertyChanged {
 public int myCoynt;

     public int MyCoynt {
        get { return myCoynt; }
        set {
            myCoynt = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

     protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged(
        [CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "") {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
}
```

Comment: The `Binding` needs a `Path`, i.e `{Binding MyCoynt, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`

Comment: it does not work, I dont think that it can find MyCoynt

Comment: Have you set the Testclass to be the `DataContext`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```xml
<TextBlock x:Name="filterAllText" 
    Text="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Path=MyCoynt}" />
```

And set your `DataContext` like:

```
filterAllText.DataContext = LogSession.test;
```

Answer (score 0):

```xml
<TextBlock x:Name="filterAllText" Text="{Binding Path=., UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

this should work but its not the usual way

EDIT: the better way is the anwser from Goanne

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066262/special-symbols-in-wpf-binding-what-does-binding-path-mean

Comment: oh, I didn't see that he set the `DataContext` to the actual property. Cool trick :)