# Textblock binding not working in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a xaml text block defined like this:

```
 <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="307,43,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="105" Width="230" Text="{Binding Supplier}"/>
```

I'm trying to bind to the property Supplier.

My constructor for the Xaml window code-behind class:

```
InitializeComponent();
viewModel = new NewOrderViewModel();
DataContext = viewModel;
```

There I explicitly set DataContext to be my viewModel object, which contains Supplier property.

And my viewModel prop:

```
public SupplierDto Supplier
        {
            get
            {
                return supplier;
            }
            set
            {
                supplier = value;
            }
        }
```

Isn't this all I have to do (set DataContext to an appropriate object), and have all public properties available for binding as I see fit?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF TextBlock text Binding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14624373/wpf-textblock-text-binding)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your viewmodel has to implement INotifyPropertyChanged and you have to call NotifyPropertyChanged() method in Supplier setter.

Comment: Thank you, as someone new to WPF, things at start can be very confusing :)