# Update Textblock value dynamically (Update)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dynamic, textblock

Hi Guys I'm trying to dynamically update a textblock by reading a value over TCP/IP. What am I doing wrong and how can I solve it? Also if there is a better way to do things I'm opening to learning.

Here I'm using a public static to use this class in other classes.

I've now implemented INotifyPropertyChanged and added the binding but its still not working as expected, what am I do

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Script_Launcher.Validation
{
    //Global variable to read message elsewhere in the code.
    public class Message
    {
        private static string message = "";

        public static string Messager
        {
            get { return message; }
            set { message = value; }

        }
    }
}
```

Here I'm opening a exe which is acting as the client and sends data to my server.

```
using HandyControl.Data;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using Script_Launcher.Validation;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Script_Launcher.Views
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        TcpListener server;
        TcpClient clientconnection;

        private void ListBoxItem_Selected_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            

            foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("OSP_Analysis"))
            {
                process.Kill();
            }

            Process.Start(@"C:\Users\path\OSP_Analysis");

            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                //Vars
                //TcpListener server;
                //TcpClient clientconnection;

                server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8088); //Opens Server on said port
                server.Start(); //Starts listener
                Trace.WriteLine("Server started...");
                clientconnection = server.AcceptTcpClient(); //Accepts Request

                NetworkStream DataStream = clientconnection.GetStream(); //Gets data stream
                byte[] buffer = new byte[clientconnection.ReceiveBufferSize];
                int Data = DataStream.Read(buffer, 0, clientconnection.ReceiveBufferSize); //Recieves data (encoded)
                Message.Messager = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, Data); //Decodes data (python .encode() function uses the ASCII code)

                clientconnection.Close();
                server.Server.Close();
            });

        }
    }
}
```

Trying to use comparisons to update the textblock

```
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Drawing.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using static Script_Launcher.Views.OilPerformance;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging;
using System.Windows.Media;
using Script_Launcher.Validation;

namespace Script_Launcher.Views
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for OilPerformance
    /// </summary>
    public partial class OilPerformance : UserControl
    {
        public OilPerformance()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            string message = Message.Messager;
            Trace.WriteLine(message);

            if (message == "1500")
            {
                PASSFAIL.Text = "PASS!";
                PASSFAIL.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
            }
            else if (message == "1501")
            {
                PASSFAIL.Text = "FAIL!";
                PASSFAIL.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            }
            else
            {
                PASSFAIL.Text = "WAITING...";
                PASSFAIL.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Finally the XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="Script_Launcher.Views.OilPerformance"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/" 
             xmlns:hc="https://handyorg.github.io/handycontrol"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True">
    <Grid>
        <Grid Margin="20" Background="{DynamicResource RegionBrush}">
        </Grid>

        <Grid Margin="40" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <StackPanel Margin="32,64,32,32" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock x:Name="PASSFAIL" Margin="0,15,0,-15" FontSize="72"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I've now implemented INotifyPropertyChanged.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace Script_Launcher.Validation
{
    class MessageClone : ObservableObject
    {
        private string messageclone = Message.Messager;

        public string Messageclone

        {

            get { return messageclone; }
            set
            {
                messageclone = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Messageclone");
            }
        }

        public MessageClone()
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                while(true)
                {
                    if (messageclone == "1500")
                    {
                        Messageclone = "PASS!";
                        //PASSFAIL.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
                    }
                    else if (messageclone == "1501")
                    {
                        Messageclone = "FAIL!";
                        //PASSFAIL.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Messageclone = "WAITING...";
                        //Messageclone.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
                        //this.Messageclone.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        Trace.WriteLine(messageclone);
                    }
                }

            });

            
        }

        
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Script_Launcher.Validation
{
    class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged? .Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

```
        private MessageClone messageclone;
        
        public OilPerformance()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext = messageclone = new MessageClone();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Textblock binding not working in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27231196/textblock-binding-not-working-in-wpf)

Comment: No, unless I'm missing something... I need a more descriptive answer.

Comment: You are missing MVVM concept, binding to the property and implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged in the viewmodel.

Comment: I've now implemented INotifyPropertyChanged but its still not working as expected. By printing my string with trace.writeline only see the else statement. Please help.

Comment: So where are you setting the `Messageclone` to anything else than "WAITING..."...?

Answer (score 0):

Bind the `TextBlock` to the source property that you are setting in the loop on the background thread:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="PASSFAIL" Text="{Binding Messageclone}" Margin="0,15,0,-15" FontSize="72" />
```

Comment: Thanks I did implement the binding, but only the else case is evaluated for some reason. As a result my textblock only says waiting. Not sure what to do next...

Answer (score 0):

You must call directly `OnPropertyChanged` if you want to notify changes.

By calling method like bellow, you can change the value and call `OnPropertyChanged` at the same time.

```cs
protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
{
    if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
    field = value;
    OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    return true;
}
```

```
private string _test;
public string Test
{
    get => _test;
    set => SetField(ref _test, value);
}
```

Comment: The setter of the `Messageclone` property already raises the `PropertyChanged` event through the base class.