# WPF Binding Text to value in an instanced class

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding, model

I am attempting to bind a *TextBlock*'s text to a string variable located in a instanced class that comes from a separate library (DLL), but I am *new* to WPF and it's binding model so I'm not quite sure how this is done or if it is possible.  I'd like to stay away from setting the text in codebehind as I like the idea of the binding model better.

(Example of the class) From a separate library:

```
public class LoggedInUser
{
     public string Username { get; }
}
```

And then elsewhere in the program:

```
public static LoggedInUser MyUser;
```

So basically,

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyUser.Username}" />
```

Where *MyUser* is an instanced class stored elsewhere in the program.

This is what I am essentially trying to do: Simply bind *TextBlock*'s text to a string that is in an instance of a class that comes from a separate library and the instance of the class is stored in my program elsewhere.

Anyone have any ideas?  Would the text change when the value changes?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14624373/wpf-textblock-text-binding

Comment: You are telling that you `like the idea of the binding model` but you binding to a static member of some class instead of binding to a property of your model?

Comment: @vasily.sib That's the attitude!

Comment: You will find tons of tutorials on the web. Instead of asking someone to write one for you take a look at some existing and  then come back with more specialized questions. This way, I promise you, you will learn much faster. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26210/Moving-Toward-WPF-Data-Binding-One-Step-at-a-Time . MSDN is a very good source too: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-overview#creating-a-binding

Comment: @BionicCode I never asked for anyone to write me any code, I appreciate feedback however and will look more into it, thanks.

Comment: _"Would the text change when the value changes?"_ - no, unless your `MyUser` is implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.7.2) and it raises the `PropertyChanged` event on `Username` change.

Comment: That's what I figured but I just had to ask it for clarification, thank you :)