# Binding a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, xaml, datagrid

I've created a code-first C# project with Entity Framework and WPF. I have created an Entity named Personel Entity. I'm dragging and dropping that Entity to MainWindow but it doesn't show   any data. I think I have to do something  in MainWindow.xaml.cs file but I don't know what to do. Here is the DataGrid code in xaml:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="personelEntityDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="19,259,18,10" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="addressColumn" Binding="{Binding Address}" Header="Address" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ageColumn" Binding="{Binding Age}" Header="Age" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="idColumn" Binding="{Binding Id}" Header="Id" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="nameColumn" Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="phoneNumberColumn" Binding="{Binding PhoneNumber}" Header="Phone Number" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Here is the code in MainWindow.xaml.cs file :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private PersonelContext _context = new PersonelContext();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource personelEntityViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("personelEntityViewSource")));    
    }
}
```

Here is the code in PersonelContext.cs file :

```
namespace Personel
{
    public class PersonelContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<PersonelEntity> Personels { get; set; }
    }
}
```

There is nothing else about datagrid in code. I know I need to add something but I don't know what to add. Can you tell me what to do?

Comment: You need first to set your DataContext

Comment: @moez I did this : private PersonelContext _context = new PersonelContext();

Comment: the context is created in another file

Comment: could you please add more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make one Change in Xaml as below

```
ItemSource= {Binding}

to 

ItemSource= {Binding Path=.}
```

and in Code behind

```
personelEntityDataGrid.ItemSource =_context.Personels.ToList();
```

(if above not works try OR part).

or

```
personelEntityDataGrid.DataContext =_context.Personels.ToList();
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you. Can you tell me what ItemSource= {Binding Path=.} does?

Comment: In Binding Mechanism, You had to set source  property of your binded Collection(e.g DataTablem,List)  and here Path=. Means root element of the Collection. As u can see in code behind we had assigned DataContext of personelEntityDataGrid(Actual element). So Here what it consider by Binding Path=.  Here  DataGrid will be bind with the root element(List element in this case).In short, . indicates root element of the binded collection.   u can also consider below think for better understanding   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066262/special-symbols-in-wpf-binding-what-does-binding-path-mean

Answer (score 1):

Basically every binding is built on a [`DataContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext.aspx) of particular [FrameworkElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). In your case it is `DataGrid`. Data is not updated because you've not initialized data context for `UseControl`. 
Please do not confuse it with Entity Frameworks [`DbContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) which has nothing to do with controls `DataContext`.

So to make your screen working just add following line into `Window_Loaded` method:

```
this.DataContext = _context.Personels.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks. But I still can't see the data :(

Comment: Do you have anything overriding context in `xaml`?

Comment: I have some methods such as add_button_click event handler. They add, delete and modify the _context. I didn't add them because I thought they have nothing with datagrid.

Comment: Are there any items in *Personels* on `Window_Loaded`? Strongly recommend you to familiarize yourself with [`MVVM`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial).

Comment: I mean data in _context.

Comment: it says context is empty, not null.. I am shocked, there are three personnels in database.