# What's the purpose of single quotes in WPF Bindings?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

In analogy to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066262/what-does-binding-path-mean-in-wpf-binding), I am curious how to interpret the expression `{Binding ''}` in WPF.
<sub>Note that there are two apostrophes after *Binding*.</sub>

In addition to a Google search I looked at [this link](http://www.nbdtech.com/Free/WpfBinding.pdf) provided in the linked question above, but was not able to assert the meaning of the two apostrophes after *Binding*.

What I came across were String Format expressions, where the apostrophe is used inside double quotes to denote another String expression. But I doubt this is the case here, for this question.

What does this expression mean?

Comment: It's equivalent to an empty Path. The apostrophes simply enclose whatever you write between them. So in your case it's a Binding to the DataSource (without a Path) - although I have to say, I've never seen it used that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's equivalent to an empty Path. The apostrophes simply enclose whatever you write between them. So in your case it's a Binding to the DataSource (without a Path) - although I have to say, I've never seen it used that way.

The reason you probably didn't find this in any Bindings related context is because it's actually a feature that is available to all XAML markup extensions (like `Binding`, `Static`, `StaticResource`, etc.).

[MSDN: Details about how markup extensions are parsed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee200269.aspx)

> The text value of either a MEMBERNAME or STRING is read as follows. Leading whitespace characters are consumed without being represented in the generated token. **If the first non-whitespace character is a quote** (either Unicode code point 0022, Quotation Mark, or 0027, Apostrophe), the tokenizer proceeds as follows:
>
> The first quote is consumed and is not represented in the token’s value.
>
> The text value becomes the characters up to but not including the next matching quote (i.e. a character of the same code point as the opening quote) that is not preceded by a “\” character. All these characters and also the closing quote are consumed. Any “\” characters in the resulting text value are removed.
>
> Whitespace characters following the closing quote are consumed, and are not represented in the token.

Take this simple (and rather useless) extension for example:

```cs
public class StringExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public StringExtension()
    { }

    public StringExtension(string value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public string Value { get; set; }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return Value;
    }
}
```

The extension could be used like this (all identical results):

```xaml
<!-- via constructor (1 argument) -->
<TextBlock Text="{local:String text}"/>

<!-- via constructor (1 argument) -->
<TextBlock Text="{local:String 'text'}"/>

<!-- via empty constructor + named property -->
<TextBlock Text="{local:String Value=text}"/>

<!-- via empty constructor + named property -->
<TextBlock Text="{local:String Value='text'}"/>
```

So, what are the `'`s used for? Well for example **for leading and trailing Whitespaces**.

```
<!-- no whitespaces -->
<TextBlock Text="{local:String      text    }"/>

<!-- whitespaces -->
<TextBlock Text="{local:String '    text    '}"/>
```